# Illuminate Class editing doesn't take effect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm facing a problem in my code and, I think, the easier solution seems to edit an Illuminate Class of the Laravel Framework.

So I opened the file I wanted to edit (`public/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php`) and added a method `headers` which returns all the response headers :

```
public function headers()
{
    return $this->headers;
}
```

But, this edit doesn't seem to be applied because, when I want to use:

```
Route::filter('cache.put', function($route, $request, $response){
    $headers = $response->headers();
});
```

the `Call to undefined method` error is thrown.

My question is : how can I edit a Laravel Class ?

Comment: you call the method in a static way (::)

Comment: In fact, no. I use `$response->headers()` in an after filter. I edited my question.

Comment: As a side note, it seems like you are using Laravel by cloning the framework project. Check the answers in here for a better way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613136/should-i-download-laravel-for-every-project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be editing code that belongs to Laravel framework directly. You'll have trouble with updating the framework later on. Even if you managed to make it work the way you're trying, it has the potential to break your whole project since Laravel will still be using it's own Response class, while you try to use your own.

You need to check out the docs about `Facades` here to do it the Laravel way: http://laravel.com/docs/facades

In short, since the Response class you will be calling is a `Facade`, you need to replace Laravel's `Response` facade with one of your own, with your custom facade pointing to your own response class. Something like this:

MyResponseFacade.php:

```
<?php namespace MyApp;

class MyResponseFacade extends \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response
{
    public static function make($content = '', $status = 200, array $headers = array())
    {
        return new MyResponse($content, $status, $headers);
    }
}
```

MyResponse.php

```
<?php namespace MyApp

class MyResponse extends \Illuminate\Http\Response
{
    public function headers()
    {
        return $this->headers;
    }
}
```

Then in your app.php, replace:

```
'Response'        => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response',
```

with this:

```
'Response'        => 'MyApp\MyResponseFacade',
```

And you are done! The whole Laravel app should be returning you `Response` that is your own class, and you can use the rest of your code with the same name `Response`.

Make sure you configure the autoload properly, and do `php artisan dump-autoload` so Laravel can see your new files though.

---

As a side note, it seems like you are using Laravel by cloning the framework project. Check the answers in here for a better way: [Should I download Laravel for every project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613136/should-i-download-laravel-for-every-project)

Comment: Whoops I accidentally told you to replace the app.php to `'Response' => 'MyApp\MyResponse'` which is wrong. That needs to be `'Response' => 'MyApp\MyResponseFacade'`. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know it's bad to edit the class directly, but I didn't know how to do it differently. Your solution looks nice, I validated your answer.

Comment: In fact, your code should be working, but in my case, `$response` filter parameter seems to be an `Illuminate\Http\Response.php` instance. Do you know how I can change that ?

Comment: Can you update at the bottom of your answer with another section, telling us + code of what you changed?

Comment: I created the 2 files and edited the `app.php` file as you said. That's all. And I didn't change my filter code.

Comment: I would expect you to get errors rather than defaulting back to Laravel's `Response`. Do you mind update the answer with your new code? The 3 changed files?