# Downloading the Laravel each time when creating the project?

Tags: php, laravel-5

In the console I will type below.

```
Composer create-project laravel/laravel "MyLocation" --prefer-dist
```

This will start downloading everything.

Question: Can't we copy the framework from previous created project ? Is that necessary every time to download everything from scratch ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I download Laravel for every project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613136/should-i-download-laravel-for-every-project)

Comment: actually you could reuse your laravel framework - download a blank project, zip it for later use, do `php artisan key:generate` whenever you make new project. however, you won't have the most recent laravel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy the existing Laravel projects if you want. But, you may need to modify too much of the parts for your new project.
Downloading a new one is the better option. In my personal opinion, make a laravel base project then push it into your git repository and whenever a new project starts, you only need to pull or fork from the repository and start building.

Comment: and don't forget to always do `php artisan key:generate` - multiple laravel instance in a single server that shared same application key will cause unexpected behaviour related to cookies.

Comment: "make a laravel base project then push it into your git repository" => "fork laravel from the official repo into your local one" then, configure composer to fetch it from your local repo instead of downloading from the internet.

Comment: For a plain new Laravel Project this does not make any sense... If you pull that from your own github or bitbucket account you also have to do a composer install ( unless you did really push the vendor folder to repository ) So either make a local copy of a recently donwloaded new laravel project or just create a new onw with composer.

Comment: we might have [bitbucket *offline* variant](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/pricing?tab=host-on-your-server) or some [mercurial *personal* server](https://hglabhq.com/). so, it's not out of question at all.